# Looking for ANY free GUI software to view W3C Extended Log Format files

Tags: logging

I am looking for some free GUI software (preferably for OSX/Linux) that is capable of parsing W3C Extended Log Format log files:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Log_Format

My web server stores logs in this format, and I'm looking for an alternative to looking at the log entries one-by-one via Terminal and `cat`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How else would this content be displayed other than as text?  What kind of graphics are you expecting to see?  It's a log file, it doesn't show anything graphically.

Comment: This is true. I guess what I'm looking for is the ability to load the specific fields into a spreadsheet-like view, and select/deselect fields in the log at will, and the ability to filter on a certain value (like "host" header field).

Answer (score 0):

What about [Polliwog](http://sourceforge.net/projects/polliwog/) ? It works pretty well for me.

You can define any [custom log format](http://polliwog.sourceforge.net/manual/log-entry-formats.html) you wish.

Answer (score 0):

There is [webalizer](http://www.webalizer.org/) which you can cron to auto generate html'd logs. There is also [awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/). Both of these aren't gui per se but they accomplish what you are asking for.